# How to regex "other than ~"?

Tags: php, regex

I am using regex in PHP.

From a string, I want to replace all strings that are **NOT** in this format:

```
([0-9]*\-*[0-9]+)
```

for example,

(1-2), (3-4), (1)

are fine, but

(123), (abc), (12-3)

are not accepted.

Is there a way to express

```
"except ([0-9]*\-*[0-9]+)"
```

in regex?

Comment: `([0-9]*\-*[0-9]+)` is a regex?! Either it matches or it doesn't.

Comment: `^except \(\[0-9\]\*\-\*\[0-9\]\+\)$`  :-p

Comment: to match all formats that don't match "([0-9]*\-*[0-9]+) "

Comment: Like in the question, match all those that are not in this kind of format : (1-2), (2) -> after all match all those that are NOT in "([0-9]*\-*[0-9]+)" format

Comment: Did you mean to match all three in the entire row ? Or were they 3 separate examples in a row? Because (123) matches the same way (1) is an acceptable answer too.

Comment: I gave wrong examples due to not fully understanding my own regex. Anyways, the answer selected below should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you can make use of a negative look-ahead that will restrict a more general character class, e.g. in your case it can be *any character other than `(` or `)`*:

```
\((?!\d*-?\d+\))[^()]*\)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW1cL2/2)

Note that `\(` matches a literal `(` that is followed with 0 or more characters other than `(` and `)` (due to `[^()]*`), but that are not conforming to your pattern `(\d*-?\d+)`.

If you want to remove such elements while trimming spaces and commas, you can use

```
,?\s*\((?!\d*-?\d+\))[^()]*\)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW1cL2/4)

Comment: Glad it works for you, please also consider upvoting if the answer proved helpful to you.